How to read/write the same character from/to a serial port
I am writing a character to a serial port and reading the same character from it. But I am not able to read the same character which I sent, I'm getting different characters.
#include <QGuiApplication>
#include <QQmlApplicationEngine>
#include "radialbar.h"
#include <QtSerialPort/QSerialPortInfo>
#include <QDebug>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
#if QT_VERSION < QT_VERSION_CHECK(6, 0, 0)
    QCoreApplication::setAttribute(Qt::AA_EnableHighDpiScaling);
#endif
    QGuiApplication app(argc, argv);

    QQmlApplicationEngine engine;
    qmlRegisterType<RadialBar>("CustomControls", 1, 0, "RadialBar");
    const QUrl url(QStringLiteral("qrc:/main.qml"));
    QObject::connect(&engine, &QQmlApplicationEngine::objectCreated,
        &app, [url](QObject *obj, const QUrl &objUrl) {
            if (!obj && url == objUrl)
                QCoreApplication::exit(-1);
        }, Qt::QueuedConnection);
    engine.load(url);

    // Open the serial port after the QML engine loads
    QSerialPort serialPort;
    serialPort.setPortName("/dev/ttyUSB0"); // Change this to your serial port name
    serialPort.setBaudRate(QSerialPort::Baud9600);
    serialPort.setDataBits(QSerialPort::Data8);
    serialPort.setParity(QSerialPort::NoParity);
    serialPort.setStopBits(QSerialPort::OneStop);
    serialPort.setFlowControl(QSerialPort::NoFlowControl);

    if (!serialPort.open(QIODevice::ReadWrite)) {
        qDebug() << "Failed to open serial port:" << serialPort.errorString();
        return 1;
    }

    if(serialPort.isOpen())
    {
        qDebug() << "Serial port is opened";

        char ch_tx = 'a';
        qDebug() << "Sending data is" << ch_tx;
        serialPort.write(&ch_tx);

        char ch_rx;
        if (serialPort.waitForReadyRead(5000)) {
            if (serialPort.getChar(&ch_rx)) {
                qDebug() << "Received data is" << ch_rx;
            } else {
                qDebug() << "Error reading from serial port:" << serialPort.errorString();
            }
        } else {
            qDebug() << "Timeout occurred while waiting for data to be read.";
        }
    }

    // Close the serial port
    serialPort.close();

    return app.exec();
}

I tried encoding and decoding using UTF-8, but that did not work.

What is the qDebug() output you are getting? What is connected at the other end of the serial port?

Hi, I am getting characters like $, G, 9 etc random characters. Serial port is connected to IMX8 board and I am accessing the device through minicom.

You have to send the same character back from your board for it to be read over the serial port. Also, try QSerialPortInfo and set the port using QSerialPort::setPort method, using QSerialPortInfo class you can verify the correct board using VID and PID.

You beed to show what you send and what you get (like a several characters), and other information about HW connection. Are you sure you have the same voltage levels on both sides?

maybe you have error imx8 board side.
you can check your qt application on the windows OS.
I suggest to you will install virtual serial port emulator and open two virtual serial port in bridge mode on windows.after that you will use any serialport program.
in this case you can check QT side without hardware and IMX8 software.
you can download virtual serialport program with this link
https://freevirtualserialports.com/
